# Android Firebase advanced queries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to build an android app with Firebase backend.

I read all about it, built an app that syncs with the backend, etc. what I can't figure out is how to make advanced queries without retrieving all the parent.

for example - say I scale to many users, and I want to retrieve only users that are 50 KM around me, I don't want to retrieve ALL the users and then manipulate the data. I want to retrieve ONLY the users I need.

I guess I'm looking for something more SQLish like "GET users WHERE users.location = bla bla bla".

can anyone help me ?
thanks!

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data?

Comment: GeoFire? https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#geo-queries

Comment: yes I know "equalTo()" and geofire, but they aren't enough for advanced queries like "get all users who are named 'bob' and have hair color 'black'.

Comment: That's a query on multiple values. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: thanks Frank. read that too. I think that maybe Firebase isn't right for my app. I wonder why didn't they allow simple AND query commands.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you watch the [Firebase Database for SQL Developers series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). It helps understanding how to create queries, the same way we used to do in SQL.